# Getting error while trying to import library

Tags: javascript, npm, javascript-import

I am getting this error while trying to import a library.

[image: Error]

I got this library by the command: `npm i queue`

code how I import (javascript):

`import Queue from "./node_modules/queue/index.js"`

HTML: `<script type="module" src="./gamescript.js"></script>`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As a guess: `import Queue from "./node_modules/queue/index.js"` -> `import { Queue } from "./node_modules/queue/index.js"`

Comment: I don't think browsers have any cjs compatibility like node, so you can't just `import` a cjs module.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have "type": "module" in your package.json ?

Comment: Yes, i have it in package.json